# OSB3 (particle board) got wet during roofing - does it need to be replaced?

Tags: roof, water-damage, particle-board

I'm putting up a large GRP flat roof. The builder has been AWOL for a while, and so the roof has been left with just OSB3 with no waterproof covering. It's been rained on for months and swelled to twice its original thickness.

Is this board still OK to use for the roof if I can let it dry? I can still walk on it with no problems.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but my guess is "hell, no." And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: Usually OSB3 board has a water exposure rating and it's designed for what the manufacturer considers "normal" exposure during construction.  It sounds, however, like your situation is far beyond normal.  I'd check with the manufacturer or the dealer of the product in your area for an assessment of how much water has been absorbed and if it's still safe to use.  My guess, however, is that this is going to be a total replacement job due to negligence on the part of the builder.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32820/is-it-ok-for-osb3-boards-to-get-wet-during-construction    Closely related

Comment: If it has swelled that much the bond of the strands has surely been compromised. I can almost guarantee that no manufacturer will support using it, and then you're left with a subjective risk tolerance issue. Voting to close as a duplicate, but also as opinion-based.

Comment: `The trade term OSB/3 comes from the technical class denoted in BS EN 300 for ‘load-bearing boards for use in humid conditions’. Humid in this instance meaning environments where ***boards are protected from external conditions*** but moisture content can increase because of humidity.`  [source](https://hanson-plywood.co.uk/products/osb3/)